# connectedCallback() cannot access self DOM elements

Tags: lit-element, polymer-3.x

`console.log` returns `null`.
It's unable to access to shadow DOM element after render.

```
class App extends LitElement{
 render(){
    return html`
        <div class = "cont"> lorem </div>
    `
  }

connectedCallback(){
  super.connectedCallback()  
  console.log(this.shadowRoot.querySelector(".cont"))
   }
}

customElements.define('example-el', App)
```

Answer (score 6):

When `connectedCallback()` is called, your component is not yet rendered because `render()` has not yet been called. You should use the `firstUpdated()` lifecycle callback instead. See this page for more details: https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/events#where-to-add-your-event-listeners